# android key store

Tags: android

Если из одного аккаунта выкладываем приложения, то необходимо, чтобы у каждого приложения был свой key store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не обязательно. Во время подписывания приложения указывается удобное вам хранилище и необходимый сертификат из него.

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно. В одном хранилище можно держать ключи для нескольких приложений. Главное не запутаться потом. А можно для каждого приложения свой keystore делать. Кому как удобнее.